# Xpath for Multiple table td element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

There is a webtable in which I need to select from 1st row only 2nd 3rd and 4th column. 
I have tried using AND operator to select multiple td but that xpath is not working.

**Xpath for 1st row which works good**

```
((//div[contains(@id,'ReportGridStyle_forRW')])[2]//tbody/tr)[2]
```

**Xpath to select td 2nd works good**

```
((//div[contains(@id,'ReportGridStyle_forRW')])[2]//tbody/tr)[2]//td[position()=2]
```

#### Xpath to select td  2nd 3rd and 4th column. NEED HELP not working

```
 ((//div[contains(@id,'ReportGridStyle_forRW')])[2]//tbody/tr)[2]//td[position()=2 and position()=3 and position()=4]
```

Comment: using List<WebElement> for the 3rd? (and getelementS)?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use XPath go for the following:

- `descendant` axe for traversing the table tag to locate the first tr element
- `position()` function to limit the rows to "interesting" only:

  ```
  //table/descendant::tr[1]/td[position() >= 2 and position() <= 4]
  ```

References:

- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Functions and Operators](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Also be aware that you can use [Table class](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) from the [Html Elements framework](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) - it provide you a clear API for working with Tables.

Comment: This is not working as needed  ((//div[contains(@id,'ReportGridStyle_forRW')])[2]//tbody/tr)[2]//td[position() >= 2 and position() <=5]

Comment: how can I remove  ((//div[contains(@id,'ReportGridStyle_forRW')])[2]//tbody/tr)[2] td 1 from tr

Comment: I provided you the way to extract rows from 2 to 4 inclusively from a table, I have no idea whether the rest of your query good or not unless I see the AUT code. Moreover you even failed to properly copy and paste it.